# how to limit retrieve to only 1 random work for one user instead of all the works

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have 2 tables userdatafiles & users, where i merge the 2 tables together based on common ID, to find the corresponding works attached to the ID, the following PHP code i have retrieve the works from the user, it works fine as i only want to show 1 work per user, but if a user have 2-3 works for example, it will also display the different works out..

PHP

```
<?php
    include 'dbAuthen.php';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Specialisation = "Painting"';

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $links[] = array(
                "links" => $row["Link"],
                "caption" => $row["Name"],
            );                  
        }
        shuffle($links);
        echo json_encode($links);   
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

the above code works if i only uploaded 1 work per user, what should i do to improve the code so that if a user have multiple works, it will only display a random work among the many that user has? Thanks..

Comment: `DISTINCT` and `LIMIT 1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DISTINCT to eliminate repeating userid:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(users.UserID),name,link FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Specialisation = "Painting" ORDER BY RAND()';
```

or use GROUP BY:

```
$sql = 'SELECT users.UserID,name,link FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Specialisation = "Painting" GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY RAND()';
```

Comment: i'm not sure how should i show, but when i change my query code from * to DISTINCT... my success function won't run, thus displaying no work at all.. any possible idea?

Comment: @Devon try my alternate solution. Please see the update on my answer.

Comment: can we discuss in chat and i show u a screenshot of my table?

Comment: tried as well, i think it should be users.UserID instead of user.UserID, both don't work

Comment: Oh that's weird. Maybe you need to create your table and data into fiddle for my reference.

Comment: is there a way to do DISTINCT * instead?

Comment: Nope, you need to specify which field should be filter. I have tried the GROUP BY in my own and it works fine.

Comment: hmm weird, ok i'll try it out first myself for a bit, since i have no idea how to create a database table.. haha thanks a lot tho i will let u know if i figured it out

Comment: That's really weird that you don't know how to create table. . hahaha

Comment: i'm actually being provided a database build by another team, my role is front end but i have to merge this 2 together and make it work for my project. Name,Link works but with DISTINCT(users.UserID) it doesn't work. I guess the problem is with this somehow, i will try and figure out hopefully >.<

Comment: Oh that's a sad story. Actually i'm using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT.

Comment: i see.. ok i see some improvements. i used userdatafiles.UserID and my success function runs now, experimenting with it still, make send tho since the userID to check for duplicates are from userdatafiles table

Comment: bro it works now, i'm using groups. So basically instead of users.UserID i changed it to userdatafiles.UserID, realised that rand() is just swapping the position to display the 10 images, is there a way to select a random work from the several works a user have instead?

Comment: That's good, good thing is you solve the problem with the sample solution provided, Yeah every time you run your query work field is changed I think.

Answer (score 1):

use [rand()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-rand-function.php) for random display and set limit to 1 so you will get one random record

```
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

so your query will be:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM userdatafiles JOIN users ON userdatafiles.UserID = users.UserID WHERE Specialisation = "Painting" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: this will only display only 1 portfolio on display, i have a total of 10, i want to limit the retrieving of the works from 1 user, not limiting the amount of portfolios to show, in my case there are 10, where each one shows a different user's work, my code displays the same user with different works if he has more than 1 work..

Comment: i was thinking am i able to use array to check if a same name exist throughout the index, if so, remove all duplicate same name so that there will only be left with 1? Is that possible